# How to get all cell values with cell address from Laravel excel 2.1?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to read an excel file and get all cell values with cell address. I couldn't find anything in the documentation.
(https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/getting-started/)

Comment: Have you check the menu on the left? It is everything in there... [https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/import/results.html](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/import/results.html)

Comment: Yes, I tried with it but it's not returning the cell address. I want to get cell values with the address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this using maatwebsite library, but if you want to directly get cell with the address, I think this library is able to do that https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/accessing-cells/

```
// Get the value from cell A1
$cellValue = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
```

*** EDIT**

```
$rowMax = 5;
$columnMax = 'E';
$result = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $rowMax; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($columnMax); $j++) {
        $cellName = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($j) . $i;
        $result[$cellName] = $sheet->getCell($cellName)->getValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to read an excel file and get the result with cell address. Result in an array like this is better : 
[
 'A1' => 0,
 'B1' => 0,
 'C1' => 0,
 'D1' => 0,
]

Comment: I already add some code that might help you, I'm not yet running it maybe need a little fix if have error. It will fill the $result variable with data like you want from A1:E5, you can modify the $rowMax and $columnMax variable to get more large data